# Error trying to make a class run with main

Tags: c++, std, iostream, program-entry-point

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A;

int main(){
    A aObject;
    aObject.cool();
    return 0;
}
class A{
    public:
        void cool(){
            cout << "hi";
        }
 };
```

But when I try to run it i get this error:

> ||=== Build: Debug in First (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===| In function 'int main()':|
>
> error: aggregate 'A aObject' has incomplete type and cannot be defined|
>
> ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Help!

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> using namespace std;
> class A;
>
> int main(){
>     A aObject;
> ```

At this point, the compiler only knows that there is a class called `A`. It does not yet know anything else about it. It does not know its size and it does not know how to construct an object of the class. It needs its *definition* to construct an object.

The following program works because the compiler knows the definition of the class at the point where you create an object of it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
        void cool(){
            cout << "hi";
        }
 };

int main(){
    A aObject;
    aObject.cool();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You got stuff arse over tit. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
        void cool(){
            cout << "hi";
        }
 };
int main(){
    A aObject;
    aObject.cool();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the colloquialism

Answer (score 1):

Move class A to before the main function.